# On a ChromaDB text query, is there any way to retrieve the query_text embeddings?

Tags: chromadb

On ChromaDB query.

```
results = collection.query(
    query_texts=["AUSSIE SHAMPOO MIRACULOUSLY SMOOTH 180 ML x 1"],
    n_results=3,
    include=['documents','distances','embeddings']
```

I am able to retrieve data from the vector database, but I am interested in obtaining the embeddings of the query_texts ("AUSSIE SHAMPOO MIRACULOUSLY SMOOTH 180 ML x 1") because I plan to add them to the collection (vector database) after completing some processing. Is there any way to do that?

I know I can simply run my embedding function on the query_text, but since Chroma DB query already embed it. It would be more efficient to simply retrieve that.